# Scala.js and ClassTag results in crash

Tags: scala, scala.js

I have following code in Scala and it works fine:

```
object TestVanilla {
  def callMe[A: ClassTag](f: Int => A): Array[A] = Array(f(4))
}

val res = TestVanilla.callMe(_ + "x");
println(res.mkString(", "));
```

Result:

```
4x
```

full code: http://scalafiddle.net/console/20337e889ee17ca9862a8317918ae5d9

I rewrote it to ScalaJS, but it seems to be crashing on the tag:

```
@JSExport("Test") object TestScalaJs {
  @JSExport def callMe[A: ClassTag](f: js.Function1[Int, A]): Array[A] = Array(f(4))
}
```

Call from JS:

```
var res = Test().callMe(function(x) {return x + 'x';});
console.log('TestScalaJs:', res.join(', '));
```

Crash:

```
$c_jl_Throwable.fillInStackTrace__jl_Throwable  @   VM153:4161
$c_sjsr_UndefinedBehaviorError.fillInStackTrace__jl_Throwable   @   VM153:9241
$c_jl_Throwable.init___T__jl_Throwable  @   VM153:4177
$c_sjsr_UndefinedBehaviorError.init___T__jl_Throwable   @   VM153:9248
$c_sjsr_UndefinedBehaviorError.init___jl_Throwable  @   VM153:9244
$throwClassCastException    @   VM153:196
$as_s_reflect_ClassTag  @   VM153:7824
$c_LTestScalaJs$.callMe @   VM153:2061
(anonymous function)    @   VM155:2
$s_Lscalatags_jsdom_Frag$class__applyTo__Lscalatags_jsdom_Frag__Lorg_scalajs_dom_raw_Element__V @   VM153:1108
$c_Lscalatags_JsDom$TypedTag.applyTo__O__V  @   VM153:9981
$c_Lfiddle_Fiddle$.println__sc_Seq__V   @   VM153:2113
$c_LScalaFiddle$.init___    @   VM153:2021
$m_LScalaFiddle$    @   VM153:2034
(anonymous function)    @   VM154:1
(anonymous function)    @   VM77 resultframe?theme=light:32
```

full code: https://beetta.scalafiddle.io/sf/YzdMmU/1

Scala.js doesn't support `ClassTag`s? Or am I doing something wrong?

---

EDIT2: Created a [follow up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39314049/is-it-possilble-to-create-type-safe-library-in-scalajs-for-using-from-javascript). This one is answered, even though it didn't actually solve anything for me - my bad, I asked poorly.

Don't answer the EDIT1 here please, but rather in the follow-up question.

EDIT1: I didn't make myself clear. The code is a simplified issue from tiny library I wanted to write in ScalaJS and the library is meant to be used from JavaScript. I am looking for a way how to solve this rather trivial looking issue - creation of type-safe array and in a same time allowing JS to actually be able to easily call the method. Maybe some proxy/facade can be used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scala.js does support `ClassTag`s. Your issue is that you're expecting JavaScript to fill in Scala implicit parameters, which it cannot do. Your method definition

```
@JSExport def callMe[A: ClassTag](f: js.Function1[Int, A]): Array[A] = Array(f(4))
```

is, as usual in Scala, equivalent to

```
@JSExport def callMe[A](f: js.Function1[Int, A])(implicit ct: ClassTag[A]): Array[A] = Array(f(4))
```

which clearly highlights that there are *2* parameters to `callMe`. The Scala typechecker can automatically fill in the second (implicit) parameter, but JavaScript cannot do that. From JavaScript, you would have to *explicitly* pass the second parameter.

Comment: So there is no way this exported function can be called only with one parameter from JavaScript? I though basic types like function, array and int are seamlessly supported. Seems quite limiting from a perspective of creating libraries in ScalaJS for JavaScript. Is it even possible? :-/

Comment: And, how to pass parameter of type ClassTag[A] from JS? Do, we need to look at the compiled JS code for that?