# Is it possilble to a create type-safe library in ScalaJS for using from JavaScript?

Tags: scala, scala.js

If so how? In my last question I asked why this snippet is crashing:

```
@JSExport("Test") object TestScalaJs {
  @JSExport def callMe[A: ClassTag](f: js.Function1[Int, A]): Array[A] = Array(f(4))
}
```

on:

```
var res = Test().callMe(function(x) {return x + 'x';});
console.log('TestScalaJs:', res.join(', '));
```

with:

```
$c_jl_Throwable.fillInStackTrace__jl_Throwable  @   VM153:4161
$c_sjsr_UndefinedBehaviorError.fillInStackTrace__jl_Throwable   @   VM153:9241
$c_jl_Throwable.init___T__jl_Throwable  @   VM153:4177
$c_sjsr_UndefinedBehaviorError.init___T__jl_Throwable   @   VM153:9248
$c_sjsr_UndefinedBehaviorError.init___jl_Throwable  @   VM153:9244
$throwClassCastException    @   VM153:196
$as_s_reflect_ClassTag  @   VM153:7824
$c_LTestScalaJs$.callMe @   VM153:2061
(anonymous function)    @   VM155:2
$s_Lscalatags_jsdom_Frag$class__applyTo__Lscalatags_jsdom_Frag__Lorg_scalajs_dom_raw_Element__V @   VM153:1108
$c_Lscalatags_JsDom$TypedTag.applyTo__O__V  @   VM153:9981
$c_Lfiddle_Fiddle$.println__sc_Seq__V   @   VM153:2113
$c_LScalaFiddle$.init___    @   VM153:2021
$m_LScalaFiddle$    @   VM153:2034
(anonymous function)    @   VM154:1
(anonymous function)    @   VM77 resultframe?theme=light:32
```

And the response was that it is because I am missing implicit argument for `callMe`. I didn't think of that before because, well, Scala is providing it auto-magically, so this just worked on a first try:

```
object TestVanilla {
  def callMe[A: ClassTag](f: Int => A): Array[A] = Array(f(4))
}

val res = TestVanilla.callMe(_ + "x");
println(res.mkString(", "));
```

The question is:

**How one is supposed to be writing type-safe** (at least in a compilation time, no need for dynamic checking) **libraries using ordinary features of Scala like integers, arrays, functions, generics and `ClassTag`s in ScalaJS which can be then easily* used from JavaScript?** I really hope it is possible.

*: I mean like no arcane requirements such as manual construction of `ClassTag`s from JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use a `js.Array` in your example:

```
@JSExport("Test") object TestScalaJs {
  @JSExport def callMe[A](f: js.Function1[Int, A]): js.Array[A] = js.Array(f(4))
}
```

`Array` is a Scala / Java style array and opaque from JavaScript (i.e. doing anything on it is undefined behavior). A `js.Array` is a JavaScript array that you can actually use from JavaScript. Like most Scala collections, it does not need a `ClassTag` to be constructed.

Comment: I am new to ScalaJS, so I really don't know what is automatically compatible and what needs to be treated a bit differently. Thank you, your solution works well.

Comment: What is and isn't directly compatible is documented at https://www.scala-js.org/doc/interoperability/types.html